# creating custom contentcontrols which support hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating some custom object using *ContentControl* and by adding them to toolbox allowing user to drag/drop them on a page. Now, I'm facing a situation where some of these controls have children. In case it is only one item without children I retrieve each object's id in Tag property, however, for the 2nd category this won't be the case, since I need to store and retrieve a hierarchy set of IDs. After few searches I ran into [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3f149b06-7dce-47c1-bab7-c70a760353c0)   and it is almost close to what I need to do but I was wondering there are better and more optimized methods of implementation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If an object *can* have more than one child you use an `ItemsControl` and not a `ContentControl`. And an `ItemsControl` containing `ItemsControls` is a hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you but I'm defining following <ItemsControl> in xaml however, it throws error message. Do I need to place it in a specific location in xaml?                                `    <!--<ItemsControl x:Key="c112" 
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Canvas.Left="210"
                    Canvas.Top="220"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Style="{StaticResource myDesign1}">
        <Image IsHitTestVisible="False" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Resources/Images/c112.png"/>

    </ItemsControl>-->`